# Assign sql query result to a macro variable in Python

Tags: python, sql, macros

I want to assign the result of this query to a variable and use that variable as a macro variable in another sql query.

1st query:

```
start_week = 201619

start_date=connection.execute("""
select min(CAST(date_id as DATE)) as start_date from date_table
where CAST(week_id as INT) = %d
"""
%(start_week))

start_date = start_date.fetchone()
```

The result of this query is : (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 2, 0, 0),)

2nd query : Now I want to use this as a macro variable in the second query

```
start_wk=connection.execute("""
select fis_week_id as start_wk from date_dim
where date_id = %s
"""
%(start_date))
```

However, I get an error such as :

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00936: missing expression
 [SQL: '\nselect week_id as start_wk from date_dim\nwhere date_id = (datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 4, 0, 0),)\n']
```

I'd appreciate if someone shows me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply string format the datetime to a string in the format: `'YYYY-M-D'` which RDBMS's read as datetime. Additionally, pass the date as a parameter not interpolated in the SQL string. See [Oracle+Python](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) best practices:

```
str_start_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(start_date[0], '%Y-%m-%d')

cur = connection.cursor()

start_wk = cur.execute("""
   select fis_week_id as start_wk 
   from date_dim
   where date_id = to_date(:sdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')""", {'sdate':str_start_date})

cur.close()
```

However, consider combining both queries without need of an intermediary variable where first query becomes a subquery in the second query's `WHERE` clause:

```
cur = connection.cursor()

start_wk = cur.execute("""
   select fis_week_id as start_wk 
   from date_dim
   where date_id = (select min(CAST(date_id as DATE)) as start_date 
                    from date_table
                    where CAST(week_id as INT) = :sweek)""", {'sweek':start_week})
cur.close()
```

Comment: Are you trying to say something? Please post the error (usually last lines of traceback) and not code. And why aren't you using the cursor object for `execute()`?

Comment: hi- when I run the first query, I get this error : DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
 [SQL: '\n   select fis_week_id as start_wk \n   from date_dim\n   where date_id = :sdate'] [parameters: {'sdate': '2016-07-04'}]

Comment: See update. For Oracle you need to wrap datetime strings with `to_date()`.